# Are questions about software for gaming hardware on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, gaming-hardware

I have a Razer gaming keyboard, which comes with a software/driver package called  [Razer Synapse](http://www.razerzone.com/synapse/). This software is required to change many of the settings associated with the keyboard, such as lighting, macros, statistics, etc.

I [was wondering where to ask a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275820/should-questions-about-drivers-for-gaming-hardware-go-to-arqade-or-super-user) earlier today. Even though Arqade is my main SE site, I was unsure wether or not my question would be on-topic at Arqade. So I think it might be a good idea to ask the community.

Are questions about **software and drivers** for **gaming related hardware** on-topic on Arqade?

Comment: Link to question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256323/how-can-i-change-the-default-profile-in-razer-synapse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes.

Razer Synapse falls under

> - Game-specific hardware and utilities

and is therefore on-topic.

Besides "help says it is on-topic", as gamers we are more likely to be familiar with this particular software than someone on superuser, for example.

That said, this *is* limited to software for actual gaming peripherals (subject to subjectivity) and *only* for use with games. A question about using a midi controller to control stuff in photoshop is off-topic.